# Use regex with grep to filter data from the output of a verbose command

Tags: regex, linux, grep, centos, command-line-interface

I am working with a cloud environment and there is a command that will display all available information about VMs running. here is an example of some of the lines that pertain to one VM.

```
RESERVATION     r-6D0F464B      170506678332    GroupD
INSTANCE        i-E9B444A9      emi-376642D8    999.99.999.999  88.888.88.888   running lock_key        0               c1.xlarge       2013-06-17T18:40:56.270Z         cluster01       eki-E7E242A3                    monitoring-disabled     999.99.999.999  88.888.88.888 ebs
```

I need to be able to pull the `i-********`, `emi-********`, both IP address, its status, the `lock_key`, the `c1.xlarge`, and the monitoring-disabled/enabled.

I have been able to pull the whole line with some super simple regex but all of this is well beyond me. If there is another easier method of grabbing this data any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Regex is the way to go here unless you have that data available in other than plain text forms.

Comment: read about `awk`, it is designed to solve this class of problem with the least amount of pain. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go by parts. Best way I can think of is redirecting the output to a file, in unix-like environments you do it like:

```
cat your-command > filename.txt
```

Second, you need to read the file line by line, I would use a python script or a perl script if you know any of those, or whatever language fits you.

Third, you can get values two different ways:

1. Read columns by position, you can get colums with a regex like: `[^\s]+`
2. Write regular expressions for every specific column, so for IP you could have something like this: `([0-9]{1,3}\.){4}` for monitoring `monitoring-([^\s]+)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the fields will always be in the same order, all you need to is split on whitespace.

Pseudocode (well, it's ruby, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
vms = {}
File.open('vm-info').readlines.each do |line|
   fields = line.split('\s+')
   field_map = {}
   vm_name = fields[<index_of_vm_name>]

   field_map['emi'] = fields[<index_of_emi>]
   field_map['ip_address'] = fields[<index_of_ip_address]
   .
   .
   .
   vms[vm_name] = field_map
end
```

After this, vms will be initialized to contain information about each vm. You can simply print them all out at this point, or continue running data manipulation on them.